# Wordpress add a div around All images in Content section of "custom post type"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I want to put a div around all images which are in the content section of a specific custom post type. I tried to stitch together some answeres to questions i found here. But since i don't know the syntacs that well, i don't know what i'am doing wrong. Maybe someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm try this

```html
add_filter("the_content", "my_content_modification");
function my_content_modification($content) {
  $post_type = get_post_type();
  $post_type_to_check = "MY_POST_TYPE";

  if ($post_type == $post_type_to_check) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)>/', '<div class="my-div"><img$1/></div>', $content);
  }

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the class for the img if somebody needs it in there as well. Thank you again Jordan Carter.

```
add_filter("the_content", "my_content_modification");
function my_content_modification($content) {
  $post_type = get_post_type();
  $post_type_to_check = "MY_POST_TYPE";

  if ($post_type == $post_type_to_check) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)>/', '<div class="MY_DIV"><img class="MY_IMG" $1/></div>', $content);
  }

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: You may want to put the "$1" directly after the end quote "MY_IMG". The $1 displays everything within the "(.*?)" section, meaning everything in the img tag between <img and >. So I think that by adding that space you're technically adding an extra space.